# TCPDF Works but is displaying numbers with each image?

Tags: image, tcpdf

So the code I have is:

> $imgdata = base64_decode($img);
>
> $imgdata = $pdf->Image('@'.$imgdata);
>
> $right_column = $imgdata.'HTML';
>
> $left_column = $imgdata.'HTML';
>
> $pdf->writeHTMLCell(90, '', '', $y, $left_column, 0, 0, 1, true, 'J', true);
>
> $pdf->writeHTMLCell(90, '', '', '',  $right_column, 0, 1, 1, true, 'J', true);

Which outputs as:

http://s21.postimg.org/tvzzua34n/problem.jpg

How can I remove the numbers?